# Add id to parser html element?

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

I'm going to write a tool that extracts data from [soccerway.com](http://it.soccerway.com/national/italy/serie-a/20152016/regular-season/r31554/). In fact I'm going to create a sort of historical.

As you can see the data is grouped into football seasons, so there would be database `2015/2016,  2016/2017` and so on. What I do then is take the data, enter them in the database and then run a cron job that goes to update these values. The problem is that I should have a key recognition on them to upgrade or something. I currently have in mind only the operation of the parser, but I do not know how I can create a key for each item parserd. For example, take the league standings from the link that I have provided you, how can I (once entered data), in the future, check with cronjob that there are updates and replace the values?
I know that to see if there are updates could exploit the field lastUpdate header and save it somewhere in the database, then the cronjob going to check this field for each league. The most important point, however, is to recognize the values ​​to be updated because I have no id to reference.

Some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While parsing the data, you can store date & time of the forthcoming matches and set the script to run then (the won't be updates in the meanwhile). If you directly parse HTML code it shouldn't take long.

Comment: uhm the problem here is recognize each item not the matc only

Comment: Oh in that case I think the most straightforward solution is to store the entire page code into a file and compare it each time with the on-line version to check for updates